# Does the derived class method override the base class version of the method in case the CRTP is used?

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp, static-polymorphism

A couple days ago I found an interesting C++ construct named *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* (usually known under abbreviation CRTP). From that time I have been attempting to fully understand how does this trick work.

Let's say I have following code snippet

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct GraphicalObject
{
    void draw()
    {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->draw();
    }
};

struct Circle : GraphicalObject<Circle>
{
    void draw()
    {
        std::cout << "Drawing circle!" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Square : GraphicalObject<Square>
{
    void draw()
    {
        std::cout << "Drawing square!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    Square s;
    Circle c;
    
    s.draw();
    c.draw();
    
    return 0;
}
```

All the "magic" behind the CRTP is obviously in the line `static_cast<T*>(this)->draw()`. But how does it work in detail? My understanding was following. Let's say I have the `Circle c`.

In case the compiler see this declaration it is a signal for him to instantiate the `GraphicalObject` template with argument `Circle`. I think that this results in creation of the struct `GraphicalObject<Circle>` by the compiler

```
struct GraphicalObject<Circle>
{
 void draw()
 {
  static_cast<Circle*>(this)->draw();
 }
};
```

So struct with a special version of the `draw` method is created. The struct `GraphicalObject<Circle>` forms the base struct for the `Circle` struct.

In the second step the instance `c` of the `Circle` struct is created i.e. the implicit constructor of the `Circle` is invoked. Due to the fact that the `Circle` is inherited from the `GraphicalObject<Circle>` the implicit constructor of that struct is invoked at first. This results in creation of an instance of the `GraphicalObject<Circle>` inside the `c` object in my opinion. Is it right? Then I think that the `draw` method declared in the `Circle` struct overrides the `draw` method declared in the `GraphicalObject<Circle>` struct. But this doesn't make sense for me. I would rather expect that the "specialized" version of the `draw` method comming from the `GraphicalObject<Circle>` shall not be overridden. Please can you tell me what is wrong in my understanding how the CRTP works?

Comment: `Circle::draw` doesn't override `GraphicalObject<Circle>::draw` (as not virtual) but hides it.

Comment: And indeed, idea is to use different name.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you for your response. Does it mean that my understanding how the CRTP works is basically correct but the `Circle::draw` hides the `GraphicalObject<Circle>::draw` instead of override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything polymorphically in `main` which would demonstrate the features of CRTP. Try this instead and see what happens:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void drawObject(GraphicalObject<T>& obj) {
    obj.draw();
}

int main() {
    Square s;
    Circle c;
    
    s.draw();
    c.draw();

    drawObject(s);  // what happens here?

    GraphicalObject<Circle>& c_ref = c;
    drawObject(c_ref);  // what happens here?
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do I understand correctly that in case I call the `drawObject(s)` the slicing takes place and the `s` is sliced to the `GraphicalObject<Square>`. Due to this the polymorphic version of the `draw` method is invoked at first?

Comment: I think you've got it. The "sliced" ([not really slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)) `obj` in `drawObject` calls the base class `draw` method, which then calls the child class `draw` in turn. This lets you create pseudo-virtual functions without defining them as `virtual` (i.e. static polymorphism).